# Weighted Cross Tab with one weight per Variables

Tags: r, crosstab

I'm looking for a more elegant solution to the following problems 
I have a data frame with 80 columns, the first 40 cols are 40 categorical variables with 6 factors, the last 40 cols are weight for each of those variables

The table looks as follow : 
[image]

I want to have a results matrix that sum.weight all the variables with their corresponding Weight.

To have a "result" matrix as follow : 
[image]

I found a solution with a loop that go through the first matrix :

for(i in 1:40){
    WKC[i,]<- xtabs(VaW[,i+40]~VaW[,i])}

This does work, but it's not the most elegant solution, furthermore, if the weights were not in order this won't work.

Is there any other mean to do that ?

```
dput(head(VaW))

structure(list(V1 = structure(c(4L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), .Label = c("A", 
"I", "M", "P", "Q", "R"), class = "factor"), V2 = structure(c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, 5L, NA), .Label = c("A", "I", "M", "P", "Q", "R"), class = "factor"), 
    V3 = structure(c(NA, NA, NA, 2L, NA, NA), .Label = c("A", 
    "I", "M", "P", "Q", "R"), class = "factor"), V4 = structure(c(NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_
    ), .Label = c("A", "I", "M", "P", "Q", "R"), class = "factor"), 
    V5 = structure(c(NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_), .Label = c("A", "I", "M", "P", 
    "Q", "R"), class = "factor"), V6 = structure(c(NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_
    ), .Label = c("A", "I", "M", "P", "Q", "R"), class = "factor"), 
    V7 = structure(c(NA, NA, 5L, NA, NA, NA), .Label = c("A", 
    "I", "M", "P", "Q", "R"), class = "factor"), V8 = structure(c(NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, 2L), .Label = c("A", "I", "M", "P", "Q", 
    "R"), class = "factor"), V9 = structure(c(2L, 1L, NA, NA, 
    NA, 5L), .Label = c("A", "I", "M", "P", "Q", "R"), class = "factor"), 
    V10 = structure(c(NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_), .Label = c("A", "I", 
    "M", "P", "Q", "R"), class = "factor"), V11 = structure(c(NA, 
    1L, NA, NA, NA, NA), .Label = c("A", "I", "M", "P", "Q", 
    "R"), class = "factor"), V12 = structure(c(NA, 2L, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA), .Label = c("A", "I", "M", "P", "Q", "R"), class = "factor"), 
    V13 = structure(c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 5L, NA), .Label = c("A", 
    "I", "M", "P", "Q", "R"), class = "factor"), V14 = structure(c(NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, 5L, NA), .Label = c("A", "I", "M", "P", "Q", 
    "R"), class = "factor"), V15 = structure(c(NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_), .Label = c("A", 
    "I", "M", "P", "Q", "R"), class = "factor"), V16 = structure(c(NA, 
    4L, NA, NA, NA, 5L), .Label = c("A", "I", "M", "P", "Q", 
    "R"), class = "factor"), V17 = structure(c(NA, NA, 4L, NA, 
    NA, NA), .Label = c("A", "I", "M", "P", "Q", "R"), class = "factor"), 
    V18 = structure(c(NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_), .Label = c("A", "I", 
    "M", "P", "Q", "R"), class = "factor"), V19 = structure(c(NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, 5L), .Label = c("A", "I", "M", "P", "Q", 
    "R"), class = "factor"), V20 = structure(c(NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_), .Label = c("A", 
    "I", "M", "P", "Q", "R"), class = "factor"), V21 = structure(c(NA, 
    1L, 4L, NA, NA, NA), .Label = c("A", "I", "M", "P", "Q", 
    "R"), class = "factor"), V22 = structure(c(NA, NA, NA, 2L, 
    1L, NA), .Label = c("A", "I", "M", "P", "Q", "R"), class = "factor"), 
    V23 = structure(c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 5L, NA), .Label = c("A", 
    "I", "M", "P", "Q", "R"), class = "factor"), V24 = structure(c(NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_
    ), .Label = c("A", "I", "M", "P", "Q", "R"), class = "factor"), 
    V25 = structure(c(4L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), .Label = c("A", 
    "I", "M", "P", "Q", "R"), class = "factor"), V26 = structure(c(NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_
    ), .Label = c("A", "I", "M", "P", "Q", "R"), class = "factor"), 
    V27 = structure(c(NA, NA, NA, 1L, NA, NA), .Label = c("A", 
    "I", "M", "P", "Q", "R"), class = "factor"), V28 = structure(c(4L, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), .Label = c("A", "I", "M", "P", "Q", 
    "R"), class = "factor"), V29 = structure(c(4L, NA, 4L, NA, 
    NA, NA), .Label = c("A", "I", "M", "P", "Q", "R"), class = "factor"), 
    V30 = structure(c(NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_), .Label = c("A", "I", 
    "M", "P", "Q", "R"), class = "factor"), V31 = structure(c(NA, 
    NA, NA, 5L, NA, NA), .Label = c("A", "I", "M", "P", "Q", 
    "R"), class = "factor"), V32 = structure(c(NA, NA, NA, 3L, 
    NA, NA), .Label = c("A", "I", "M", "P", "Q", "R"), class = "factor"), 
    V33 = structure(c(NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_), .Label = c("A", "I", 
    "M", "P", "Q", "R"), class = "factor"), V34 = structure(c(NA, 
    NA, NA, 1L, 5L, NA), .Label = c("A", "I", "M", "P", "Q", 
    "R"), class = "factor"), V35 = structure(c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, 2L), .Label = c("A", "I", "M", "P", "Q", "R"), class = "factor"), 
    V36 = structure(c(NA, 4L, NA, 1L, NA, 5L), .Label = c("A", 
    "I", "M", "P", "Q", "R"), class = "factor"), V37 = structure(c(NA, 
    1L, 4L, NA, NA, NA), .Label = c("A", "I", "M", "P", "Q", 
    "R"), class = "factor"), V38 = structure(c(NA, NA, 4L, NA, 
    6L, NA), .Label = c("A", "I", "M", "P", "Q", "R"), class = "factor"), 
    V39 = structure(c(6L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), .Label = c("A", 
    "I", "M", "P", "Q", "R"), class = "factor"), V40 = structure(c(4L, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), .Label = c("A", "I", "M", "P", "Q", 
    "R"), class = "factor"), V41 = structure(c(NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_), .Label = c("A", 
    "I", "M", "P", "Q", "R"), class = "factor"), V42 = structure(c(NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_
    ), .Label = c("A", "I", "M", "P", "Q", "R"), class = "factor"), 
    V43 = structure(c(NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_), .Label = c("A", "I", 
    "M", "P", "Q", "R"), class = "factor"), V1.freq = c(1.03191489361702, 
    1.03191489361702, 1.03191489361702, 1.03191489361702, 1.03191489361702, 
    1.03191489361702), V2.freq = c(0.908805031446541, 0.908805031446541, 
    0.908805031446541, 0.908805031446541, 0.908805031446541, 
    0.908805031446541), V3.freq = c(1.1231884057971, 1.1231884057971, 
    1.1231884057971, 1.1231884057971, 1.1231884057971, 1.1231884057971
    ), V4.freq = c(1.12454212454212, 1.12454212454212, 1.12454212454212, 
    1.12454212454212, 1.12454212454212, 1.12454212454212), V5.freq = c(1, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1), V6.freq = c(0.866043613707165, 0.866043613707165, 
    0.866043613707165, 0.866043613707165, 0.866043613707165, 
    0.866043613707165), V7.freq = c(0.961904761904762, 0.961904761904762, 
    0.961904761904762, 0.961904761904762, 0.961904761904762, 
    0.961904761904762), V8.freq = c(1.07801418439716, 1.07801418439716, 
    1.07801418439716, 1.07801418439716, 1.07801418439716, 1.07801418439716
    ), V9.freq = c(0.966996699669967, 0.966996699669967, 0.966996699669967, 
    0.966996699669967, 0.966996699669967, 0.966996699669967), 
    V10.freq = c(1.01941747572816, 1.01941747572816, 1.01941747572816, 
    1.01941747572816, 1.01941747572816, 1.01941747572816), V11.freq = c(1.12222222222222, 
    1.12222222222222, 1.12222222222222, 1.12222222222222, 1.12222222222222, 
    1.12222222222222), V12.freq = c(1.1268115942029, 1.1268115942029, 
    1.1268115942029, 1.1268115942029, 1.1268115942029, 1.1268115942029
    ), V13.freq = c(1.00990099009901, 1.00990099009901, 1.00990099009901, 
    1.00990099009901, 1.00990099009901, 1.00990099009901), V14.freq = c(0.973333333333333, 
    0.973333333333333, 0.973333333333333, 0.973333333333333, 
    0.973333333333333, 0.973333333333333), V15.freq = c(0.87202380952381, 
    0.87202380952381, 0.87202380952381, 0.87202380952381, 0.87202380952381, 
    0.87202380952381), V16.freq = c(1.08988764044944, 1.08988764044944, 
    1.08988764044944, 1.08988764044944, 1.08988764044944, 1.08988764044944
    ), V17.freq = c(1.02333333333333, 1.02333333333333, 1.02333333333333, 
    1.02333333333333, 1.02333333333333, 1.02333333333333), V18.freq = c(0.983974358974359, 
    0.983974358974359, 0.983974358974359, 0.983974358974359, 
    0.983974358974359, 0.983974358974359), V19.freq = c(0.993265993265993, 
    0.993265993265993, 0.993265993265993, 0.993265993265993, 
    0.993265993265993, 0.993265993265993), V20.freq = c(1.03883495145631, 
    1.03883495145631, 1.03883495145631, 1.03883495145631, 1.03883495145631, 
    1.03883495145631), V21.freq = c(1.07070707070707, 1.07070707070707, 
    1.07070707070707, 1.07070707070707, 1.07070707070707, 1.07070707070707
    ), V22.freq = c(1.20689655172414, 1.20689655172414, 1.20689655172414, 
    1.20689655172414, 1.20689655172414, 1.20689655172414), V23.freq = c(1.05925925925926, 
    1.05925925925926, 1.05925925925926, 1.05925925925926, 1.05925925925926, 
    1.05925925925926), V24.freq = c(1.08070175438596, 1.08070175438596, 
    1.08070175438596, 1.08070175438596, 1.08070175438596, 1.08070175438596
    ), V25.freq = c(1.17602996254682, 1.17602996254682, 1.17602996254682, 
    1.17602996254682, 1.17602996254682, 1.17602996254682), V26.freq = c(1.00333333333333, 
    1.00333333333333, 1.00333333333333, 1.00333333333333, 1.00333333333333, 
    1.00333333333333), V27.freq = c(0.970873786407767, 0.970873786407767, 
    0.970873786407767, 0.970873786407767, 0.970873786407767, 
    0.970873786407767), V28.freq = c(0.986798679867987, 0.986798679867987, 
    0.986798679867987, 0.986798679867987, 0.986798679867987, 
    0.986798679867987), V29.freq = c(1.17894736842105, 1.17894736842105, 
    1.17894736842105, 1.17894736842105, 1.17894736842105, 1.17894736842105
    ), V30.freq = c(0.993710691823899, 0.993710691823899, 0.993710691823899, 
    0.993710691823899, 0.993710691823899, 0.993710691823899), 
    V31.freq = c(1.003367003367, 1.003367003367, 1.003367003367, 
    1.003367003367, 1.003367003367, 1.003367003367), V32.freq = c(0.986531986531987, 
    0.986531986531987, 0.986531986531987, 0.986531986531987, 
    0.986531986531987, 0.986531986531987), V33.freq = c(1.02456140350877, 
    1.02456140350877, 1.02456140350877, 1.02456140350877, 1.02456140350877, 
    1.02456140350877), V34.freq = c(1.01923076923077, 1.01923076923077, 
    1.01923076923077, 1.01923076923077, 1.01923076923077, 1.01923076923077
    ), V35.freq = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), V36.freq = c(0.933333333333333, 
    0.933333333333333, 0.933333333333333, 0.933333333333333, 
    0.933333333333333, 0.933333333333333), V37.freq = c(1.10112359550562, 
    1.10112359550562, 1.10112359550562, 1.10112359550562, 1.10112359550562, 
    1.10112359550562), V38.freq = c(0.971428571428571, 0.971428571428571, 
    0.971428571428571, 0.971428571428571, 0.971428571428571, 
    0.971428571428571), V39.freq = c(1.08960573476702, 1.08960573476702, 
    1.08960573476702, 1.08960573476702, 1.08960573476702, 1.08960573476702
    ), V40.freq = c(1.02777777777778, 1.02777777777778, 1.02777777777778, 
    1.02777777777778, 1.02777777777778, 1.02777777777778), V41.freq = c(1.03225806451613, 
    1.03225806451613, 1.03225806451613, 1.03225806451613, 1.03225806451613, 
    1.03225806451613), V42.freq = c(0.962962962962963, 0.962962962962963, 
    0.962962962962963, 0.962962962962963, 0.962962962962963, 
    0.962962962962963), V43.freq = c(1.04040404040404, 1.04040404040404, 
    1.04040404040404, 1.04040404040404, 1.04040404040404, 1.04040404040404
    )), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Can you include the output from `dput(head(VaW))` in your question please?

Comment: yes ! I just edited it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `VaW` is different from the table in your screenshot (e.g. no `Subject` column, there are 43 variables, the names of weight columns are `Vxx.freq`), so I will use the `VaW` you provided in the `dput` output.

Your solution works fine! If you're worried about column ordering, you can just use the column names instead of column indices. Below, I use the `sprintf` function: `sprintf("V%d.freq", i)` replaces `%d` with the value of `i`.  I also use `lapply` and `rbind` the results.

```
out <- lapply(1:43, function(i) {
  xtabs(VaW[, sprintf("V%d.freq", i)] ~ VaW[, sprintf("V%d", i)])
})
WKC <- do.call(rbind, out)
rownames(WKC) <- paste0("V", 1:43)
```

This gives you

```
WKC
#             A         I        M         P         Q         R
# V1  0.0000000 0.0000000 0.000000 1.0319149 0.0000000 0.0000000
# V2  0.0000000 0.0000000 0.000000 0.0000000 0.9088050 0.0000000
# V3  0.0000000 1.1231884 0.000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000
# V4  0.0000000 0.0000000 0.000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000
# V5  0.0000000 0.0000000 0.000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000
# <snip>
```